# Get-MsalToken Error : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm getting the error below when executing this script attempting to generate a TAP in Azure AD:

```
$tenantId = "**********"
$clientID = "**********"
$ClientSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString "**********" -AsPlainText -Force
$Scope = "https://**************"
$redirectUri = "https://***************"
$TokenResponse = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientID -clientsecret $clientsecret -TenantId $tenantId -Interactive -RedirectUri $redirectUri -Scopes $Scope
```

It errors as follows:
Get-MsalToken : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:18
+ $TokenResponse = get-msaltoken @connectiondetails
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-MsalToken], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Get-MsalToken

I cannot figure out what is wrong. Any input to assist will be greatly appreciated!

I attempted running the script without the -clientsecret paramater and I get this error:

Get-MsalToken : A configuration issue is preventing authentication - check the error message from the server for details. You can modify the configuration in the application registration portal. See
https://aka.ms/msal-net-invalid-client for details.  Original exception: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
Trace ID: 478c441b-12e4-4968-a485-066872501300
Correlation ID: 55cf72cb-7c3c-4f4e-a26c-cfe746bb5985
Timestamp: 2023-01-15 22:04:27Z
At line:1 char:18

- ... nResponse = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientID -TenantId $tenantId  -I ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (Microsoft.Ident...arameterBuilder:AcquireTokenInteractiveParameterBuilder) [Write-Error], MsalServiceException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetMsalTokenFailureAuthenticationError,Get-MsalToken

Comment: https://github.com/AzureAD/MSAL.PS/blob/master/src/Get-MsalToken.ps1 implies that you cannot combine `-Interactive` with `-ClientSecret` - they are in different parameter sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

When I ran the script without **`Client-Secret`**, I got the below error:

[image]

I agree with *mklement0*, `-Interactive` with `-ClientSecret` is not feasible to use in one script while generating the token via **`Get-MsalToken`**.

I excluded **`-Interactive`**  from the script and access token generated successfully like below:

```
$tenantId = "TenantID"
$clientID = "ClientID"
$ClientSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString "ClientSecret" -AsPlainText -Force
$Scope = "Scope"
$redirectUri = "RedirectURI"
$TokenResponse = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $clientID -clientsecret $clientsecret -TenantId $tenantId -RedirectUri $redirectUri -Scopes $Scope
```

[image]

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[PowerShell Gallery | Get-MsalToken.ps1](https://psg-prod-centralus.cloudapp.net/packages/MSAL.PS/4.36.1.2/Content/Get-MsalToken.ps1)

[Microsoft Graph Access Token Acquisition with PowerShell by Nicola Suter](https://tech.nicolonsky.ch/explaining-microsoft-graph-access-token-acquisition/)

Comment: Thank you Rukmini and MKlement0!  This worked! In addition, I was also incorrectly using the Secret Client ID instead of the Secret Client Value.  Much appreciated!